# Tic-Tac-Toe Winnner determiner?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello I have simple code here to determine if there is a win in a tic-tac-toe game.  I am having trouble getting the condition right to determine a win.

> board = [['7', '8', '9'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['1', '2', '3']]

the top row is 7,8,9 the middle 4,5,6 and the bottom 1,2,3 I wrote a if statement to detect when a winner of 'X' or 'O' has been determined.

```
   if ('X' == (board[0][0] and board[0][1] and board[0][2])) or ('O' == (board[0][0] and board[0][1] and board[0][2])):
    return True
elif ('X' == (board[1][0] and board[1][1] and board[1][2])) or ('O' == (board[1][0] and board[1][1] and board[1][2])):
    return True
elif ('X' == (board[2][0] and board[2][1] and board[2][2])) or ('O' == (board[2][0] and board[2][1] and board[2][2])):
    return True
elif ('X' == (board[0][0] and board[1][0] and board[2][0])) or ('O' == (board[0][0] and board[1][0] and board[2][0])):
    return True
elif ('X' == (board[0][1] and board[1][1] and board[2][1])) or ('O' == (board[0][1] and board[1][1] and board[2][1])):
    return True
elif ('X' == (board[0][2] and board[1][2] and board[2][2])) or ('O' == (board[0][2] and board[1][2] and board[2][2])):
    return True
elif ('X' == (board[0][0] and board[1][1] and board[2][2])) or ('O' == (board[0][0] and board[1][1] and board[2][2])):
    return True
elif ('X' == (board[0][2] and board[1][1] and board[2][0])) or ('O' == (board[0][2] and board[1][1] and board[2][0])):
    return True
else:
    return False
```

I would like for the conditions to return True if all three of the Boards are full of either X's or O's.  Sorry for the repeat question notice, I have rewrote the if statements again and wish someone could explain what I have done wrong here.  At this moment I am having lot's of issues writing these conditionals and any explanation would be much appreciated.
-Thanks

Comment: Is that code your, or is not mutable?

Comment: Try typing `('X' or 'O')` into your interactive interpreter and see what it actually means.

Comment: Just as an aside, you would be better off with a function that returned the winner (`X`, `O` or `None`, for example) rather than the fact that someone has one. Then you can act approriately in the caller and your statements become simpler: `if (board[0][0] != ' ') and (board[0][0] == board[0][1]) and (board[0][0] == board[0][2]): return board[0][0]`, returning `None` if all eight tests fail.